# How do I pass arguments to my rake task in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen similar questions here, couldn't figure out the answer I'm just starting with ror development. I've got a rake task :

```
namespace:generate do 
    desc "Export to txt"
    task :txt => :environment do |t, args|
        puts "testing #{args}"
    end
end
```

When I do this from command line:

```
rake generate:txt
```

I get `testing {}`

When I try to inject value as an argument like this :

`rake generate:txt[testvalue]` or

```
rake generate:txt testvalue
```

First one does nothing same output `testing {}` second one I get an error. So in which way do I invoke command so I populate args with some value(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you have to declare parameters explicitly.

```
task :environment do
  puts "setting up env"
end

namespace :generate do
  desc "Export to txt"
  task :txt, [:filename] => :environment do |t, args|
    puts "testing #{args}"
  end
end
```

Then

```
% rake generate:txt['foo']
setting up env
testing {:filename=>"foo"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace:generate do 
    desc "Export to txt"
    task :txt, [:arg1] =>  :environment do |t, args|
        puts "testing #{args[:arg1]}"
    end
end

rake generate:csv arg1="value"
```